# How do I close ALL modal dialogs in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

How do I close all modal dialogs? I have an app that uses a lot of modal dialogs (bottom sheets that are modal). Many can be open at the same time.

The command:

```
Navigotor.of(context).pop();
```

simply closes ONE dialog. What would be the command to close ALL modal dialogs that are open?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a popUntil method on Navigator that might do what you need:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context,ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
```

Comment: oh wow. Thanks. I was unaware. But my modal windows don't have any name. How do I name them? or how do I use this method without any name?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you should be able to do something like `Navigator.popUntil(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourPageClass()))`

Comment: Thank you very much Jay. It works like a charm (1st answer was perfect btw)